# UITableViewController extra blank space at the bottom

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` that shows about 20px height blank space at the bottom  like so. Any Ideas how to remove it? I tried setting `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` like suggested in other answers but no luck

[image]

Comment: Please share some relevant code.

Comment: The weird thing is this only happens if I create and set the window programmatically inside `sceneWillConnectTo`. If I just drag a blank `UITableViewController from the storyboard that doesn't happen.

Comment: Ah, you're using SwiftUI - that seems pretty essential information.

Comment: No I'm not. What I did is just the boilerplate code for setting up the window and setting the `window.rootViewController` as my `tableViewController`. But if I setup a `UITableViewController` inside storyboard and set it as my subclass it works without that extra space at the bottom.

Comment: Try wrapping your `tableViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil` or `self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`

Comment: Doesn't work. Btw tableView.tableFooterView is nil by default

Comment: probably there is a problem with your layout ? for example - table view has bottom margin > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting bottom inset to 0

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: Tried that as well. No luck